# How to invoke a java method asynchronously?

Tags: java, asynchronous, methods, invocation

Is there any good sample to get started with java synchronous method invocation. I have two methods a and b and have to call b asynchronously. Any suggestion?

Comment: Search tutorial in Google

Answer (score 1):

This is a big topic, with lots of gotchas. But you can get a good start by wrapping your method in a [`Callable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) and submitting that to [`ExecutorService.submit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29). That will return back a [`Future<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html), which has a method `get()`. That last method returns `T`, but not until the `Callable<T>` finished.

For instance, let's say `foo.b()` returns `String`. You'd do something like:

```
Callable<String> asyncB = new Callable<String>() {
    @Override
    public String call() {
        foo.b();
    }
};
Future<String> futureB = myExecutorService.submit(asyncB);
// asyncB will now execute on a separate thread,
// which is managed by the ExecutorService
foo.a(); // synchronous call
String resultB = futureB.get();
```

If you're on Java 8, that first bit can just be:

```
Callable<String> asyncB = () -> foo.b();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you by any chance are using Spring, they have excellent async support.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html